# Angular Firestore Document Observable not getting all data from database

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

For some reason, I am not able to access all of my data in my database. Here is the code that creates a reference to the Firestore document ('templates'), an observable for that reference, and a subscription for that observable:

```
this.templateDoc = this.afs.collection('application').doc('templates');
this.templateObs = this.templateDoc.valueChanges();
this.templateObs.subscribe(
   (templates: any) => {
    console.log('Templates object:');
    console.log(templates);
    this.proj_srv.template = templates[this.proj_srv.model];
    this.proj_srv.initiateProject();
  });
}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncrCp.png) is the console output. It shows the following object:

```
Templates object:
{
Template 1: {
         Assembly : {Photo 1: "", Photo 2: ""}      
         Assembly 2: {Photo 1: "", Photo 2: ""}
         Assembly 3: {Photo 1: "", Photo 2: ""}
        }
Template 2: { Assembly 1: {...}, Assembly 2: {...}, Assembly 3: {...} }
Template 3: { Assembly 1: {...}, Assembly 2: {...}, Assembly 3: {...} }
}
```

The problem is that all instances of the keys "Photo 1" and "Photo 2" in my database have full paths as values, not empty strings (databases pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCbPr.png)).

I really cannot see what is going wrong. Am I using the Angular Firestore module incorrectly?